# continuity if a measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a measure space. In order for $\mathbb{P}$ to be continuous from below and above, does $\mathbb{P}$ has to be finite or $\sigma$-finite is enough?

Comment: Neither is necessary. There are measure spaces equipped with neither finite nor $\sigma$-finite measures yet as long as they satisfy $\sigma$-additivity, then continuity holds.

Comment: ok,  for example?

Comment: The counting measure on the real line is an example. It is $\sigma$-additive, but you can't represent the real line as a countable union of sets with finite measure under the counting measure (for then every set in the union must be a finite set), so it is not $\sigma$-finite.